# C# How to perform Asynchrounus I/O using Completion Ports with APM-TAP Patterns on WCF Callback?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, threadpool, iocp

I am trying to utilize I/O Completion Ports using WCF Callback in a Duplex Contract. I am using the following simple line to do this:

```
OperationContext.Current.OnPushData(data);
```

Where **OnPushData** is a callback contract operation that is implemented on the client side.
Since this line is representing a Response (Output operation) using some network interface and **WCF** is also relying on **ThreadPool** threads that can be used as a worker threads or I/O CompletionPortThread, it will be a good idea to utilize I/O CompletionPortThreads by writing to completion port using **TAP or APM** Patterns (As the article I referred to is suggesting) instead of using a normal worker thread which will increase the performance considerably.

Comment: I'm not sure you're using the right tool for the job. IIUC, you're programming (read: rolling your own) a pub/sub server. Perhaps existing implementations would give you a good solution in less time. Take a look at SignalR (http://signalr.net/), Redis (http://redis.io/topics/pubsub), etc.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` is less likely to use IO threads as you wished, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericeil/archive/2008/06/20/windows-i-o-threads-vs-managed-i-o-threads.aspx as it should wrap the worker threads instead. You are using WCF in a way that against its original design. Every WCF call should be small and quick with a reasonable timeout. Like the other comment suggests, for unpredictable timeout case or long execution tasks, SignalR is a way better solution to try.

Comment: The processing time itself is not that much. Actually it is only a few milliseconds (~10) and it is running on a dedicated thread separately from WCF. I can not switch to SignalR right now, cause WCF is a standard for our company and the whole application is already built on top of WCF. I am using parallel.for each for only to call a client callback method which is pretty much defined as a Duplex contract for WCF.

Comment: Lex Li Thanks for your helpful link it explains a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:**
The trick to be able to use Async I/O with Duplex WCF Contract is the following simple code:

```
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    Task OnPushData(data);
```

Simply you need to change the return type of your callback contract method to be **Task**. but this is not enough, you need to implement an **async method** like this:

```
    public async Task PublishData()
    {
        communicationCallback = (ICommunicationObject)service.Callback;
        if (communicationCallback.State == CommunicationState.Opened)
        {
                await service.Callback.OnPushData(data);
        }
    }
```

***That is all.*** This actually boosts the performance of my application. and Now I am able to see I/O completion Ports threads utilized calling **ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(workers,IO)**

**Some Explinations:**
As I understand, to be able to use Async I/O mechanism, you will need to do the following:

1- Determining your I/O operation.
2- A method that will encapsulate your async I/O logic.
3- A callback mechanism that will be called when async I/O is finished and its purpose mainly is to get the result of the Async I/O.
4- An object that will holds your Async I/O result.

**.NET framework** provides 3 design patterns to do so:

1- **IAsyncResult Asynchrnous Pattern:** where **Beginxxx** and **Endxxx** will encapsulate your async logic along with a **Callback Delegate** that represents the callback method and of course an **IAsyncResult** object used to hold your async I/O result.
2- **Task Based Asynchronous Pattern:** Using one class only which is **Task** along with async/await keywords that facilitate the using of TAP pattern.
3- **Event Based Asynchronous Pattern.**

You can read more about how you can use these patterns with WCF Services at [How to Implement an Asynchronous Service Operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177(v=vs.110).aspx)

However, The previous link is great for implementing async request/response service, though,  there is no explanation on how to do so with callback contract.
Unfortunately, in my case I have to implement a subscriber/publisher patttern using WCF framework where data publishing is initiated by the service side periodically (each 1 second).

**More Details:**
I will try to make this as short as possible:
WCF is relying on ThreadPool provided by .NET Framework. ThreadPool has 2 kind of threads:
1- **Worker Threads:** for Compute-Bound operations.
2- **I/O Completion Port Threads:** Used to get the result of an I/O operation.

You must differentiate between IOCP Thread and IOCP Object initiated by CLR. IOCP Thread role is to deliver the result of I/O operation while IOCP Object is the one initiated by CLR to recieve all I/O requests. In other words, they collaborate to achieve I/O operation.

First thing you need to know is that any I/O request you made will result in a system call that will initiate an object Called **IRP (I/O request Packet)** whether you are using synchronous or asynchronous paradigm.

I/O Completion Port (**IOCP**) is nothing but a queue-like object initiated by the **CLR**. This object is responsible for receiving all **I/O Completed requests** (**IRPs**). At this point there are 2 possibilities here:
1- Your I/O operation is called by a synchronous method: In this case the caller thread will be blocked until your I/O operation is done.
2- Your I/O operation is called by an async method: In this case the caller thread will continue the execution and it will not be blocked for the I/O operation until completion.

Supposing that you are using async method, When your async I/O operation is completed, this means the **IRP** object is processed and now it will be queued to **IOCP** object.
**ThreadPool IOCP threads** will come to play the role of pulling the relative **IRP** from **IOCP** which will be wrapped in **IAsyncResult** for APM or **Task** object for TAP and passing this object to your application Level through a **Callback Mechanism**.

**Some References:**

> [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734701.aspx
>   [2]: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-wcf-today-and-tomorrow.html
>   [3]: http://southworks.com/blog/2013/10/29/asynchronous-io-in-c-io-completion-ports/
>   [4]: http://southworks.com/blog/2013/08/02/asynchronous-io-in-c-introduction/
>   [5]: http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2011/03/7000-concurrent-connections-with.html
>   [6]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177(v=vs.110).aspx
>   [7]: http://www.amazon.es/Clr-Via-C-Developer-Reference/dp/0735667454